# identifier "ParseNetworkString" is undefined although I included the header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio

MSVC keeps telling me that ParseNetworkString is undefined.
But I've done:

```
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
```

as expressed in the [remark part of the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-parsenetworkstring#remarks)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a look inside "iphlapi.h" and it states (line 1287)
// app must include winsock2.h, ws2ipdef.h, and windns.h to use this API

So when I use

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>
#include <WinDNS.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
```

ParseNetworkString becomes available.
So it seems you were on the right track, just missing the include of <WinDNS.h>

Comment: Thank you very much. I've learned something from you. Not to trust the docs. The code has the final saying.